# Inserting single value into nested list in Python using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, list, beautifulsoup

I have a program that extracts data from a bunch of html documents and then writes that data out to a csv file. I'm using a list of Work Order numbers to tell the application which directories to open and I want to insert the current work order number into each row that it corresponds with. I can't figure out how to insert that woNumber value into the nested list that I'm using to create my csv file. Here is the full app:

```
import os, bs4, csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

csvOut ='C:\\GLO\\Scripts\\engineering_out'
woFile = 'C:\\glo\\wos.txt'
rows = []

f = open(woFile, 'wb')
#dirList = os.listdir('E:\\Elements\\Disaster Recovery Program\\Engineering Home')
dirList = os.listdir('C:\\GLO\\Test')

for line in dirList:
    f.write(str(line) + '\n')
f.close()

f = open(woFile, 'rb')

for i in f:

    woNumber = i.rstrip('\n')

    #File paths structure
    woMetaPath = 'E:\\Elements\\Disaster Recovery Program\\Engineering Home\\'+ woNumber + '\\DocumentLibrary-Correspondence\\Correspondence.xls'

    if os.path.exists(woMetaPath):
        #Open the metadata file, find the table, and extract the data
        html = open(woMetaPath)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
        table = soup.find("table")
        for row in table.find_all('tr'):
            rows.append([val.text.encode('utf-8') for val in row.find_all('td')])    
        print 'Done with ' + woNumber
    #print 'Done with reading meta data files!'

with open((csvOut + '.csv'), 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='*')
    writer.writerows(row for row in rows if row)

print 'Done writing CSV file!'
```

An example of the structure of the data file that I'm extracting from looks like this:

```
<table id="_tblListView" border="0" style="border-color:Silver;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;">
    <tr style="background-color:Gainsboro;font-weight:bold;">
        <td>Bid Package ID</td><td>Date Rec'vd</td><td>Description</td><td>File Type</td><td>Name</td><td>Title</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td></td><td></td><td></td><td>pdf</td><td>WO 10101-1 Exhibit A, B.pdf</td><td>WO 10101-1 Exhibit A, B</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>10101-1_BID1</td><td></td><td></td><td>xlsx</td><td>10101-1_BID1_PC Submittal_Review Checklist.xlsx</td><td></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>10101-1_BID1</td><td></td><td></td><td>xlsx</td><td>10101-1_BID1_General_Review Checklist.xlsx</td><td></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>10101-1_BID1</td><td></td><td>10101-1 BID1 Generator Review Checklist</td><td>xlsx</td><td>10101-1_BID1_Generator_Review_Checklist.xlsx</td><td>10101-1 BID1 Generator Review Checklist</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>10101-1_BID1</td><td></td><td></td><td>xlsx</td><td>10101-1-1_BID1_Bid Documents_Review.xlsx</td><td></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>10101-1_BID1</td><td>4/29/2010 12:00:00 AM</td><td>Brazoria County_City of Angleton_Lift Stations 1, 4, & 7</td><td>xlsx</td><td>10101-1_bid1_ Equip Foundation_Review Checklist.xlsx</td><td>Equipment Foundation Review</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td></td><td></td><td></td><td>msg</td><td>FW  WO_10101-1_BID1_60_1.msg</td><td></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td></td><td></td><td></td><td>msg</td><td>RE  WO_10101-1_BID1_Final_1.msg</td><td></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td></td><td></td><td></td><td>msg</td><td>WO_10101-1_BID1_Final_1_Accepted.msg</td><td></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>10101-1_BID2</td><td>6/17/2010 12:00:00 AM</td><td></td><td>xlsx</td><td>10101-1_BID2_Bid_Documents_Review Checklist.xlsx</td><td></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>10101-1_BID2</td><td>6/17/2010 12:00:00 AM</td><td>10101-1_BID2_General_Review_Checklist
</td><td>xlsx</td><td>10101-1_BID2_General_Review_Checklist.xlsx</td><td>10101-1_BID2_General_Review_Checklist</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>10101-1_BID2</td><td>6/17/2010 12:00:00 AM</td><td>10101-1_BID2_Generator_Review_Checklist</td><td>xlsx</td><td>10101-1_BID2_Generator_Review_Checklist.xlsx</td><td>10101-1_BID2_Generator_Review_Checklist</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>10101-1_BID2</td><td></td><td></td><td>xlsx</td><td>10101-1_BID2_PC Submittal_Review Checklist.xlsx</td><td></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>10101-1_BID1</td><td></td><td></td><td>msg</td><td>WO 10101-1_BID1_Final_1 Rejected.msg</td><td></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>10101-1_BID1</td><td></td><td></td><td>msg</td><td>WO 10101-1_BID1_Final_2.msg</td><td></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>10101-1_BID2</td><td></td><td></td><td>msg</td><td>WO 10101-1_BID2_60_2.msg</td><td></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>10101-1_BID2</td><td></td><td></td><td>msg</td><td>WO 10101-1_BID2_Final_1 Brazoria Co (Iowa Colony).msg</td><td></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>10101-1_BID3</td><td>10/4/2010 12:00:00 AM</td><td>10101-1_BID3_Generator_Review_Checklist</td><td>xlsx</td><td>10101-1_BID3_Generator_Review_Checklist.xlsx</td><td>10101-1_BID3_Generator_Review_Checklist</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>10101-1_BID3</td><td>10/4/2010 12:00:00 AM</td><td>10101-1_BID3_General_Review_Checklist</td><td>xlsx</td><td>10101-1_BID3_General_Review_Checklist.xlsx</td><td>10101-1_BID3_General_Review_Checklist</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>10101-1_BID3</td><td></td><td></td><td>xlsx</td><td>10101-1_BID3_Building (Structural)_Review Checklists.xlsx</td><td>Commodore Cove Waste Wter and Water Plant</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>10101-1_BID3</td><td></td><td></td><td>xlsx</td><td>10101-1_BID3_PC Submittal_Review Checklist.xlsx</td><td></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>10101-1_BID3</td><td>10/5/2010 12:00:00 AM</td><td></td><td>xlsx</td><td>10101-1_BID3_Bid Documents_Review.xlsx</td><td></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>10101-1_BID3</td><td></td><td></td><td>msg</td><td>WO 10101-1_BID3_60_1 Brazoria Co.msg</td><td></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>10101-1_BID3</td><td></td><td></td><td>msg</td><td>WO 10101-1_BID3_Final_1 Brazoria Co.msg</td><td></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>10101-1_BID3</td><td></td><td></td><td>msg</td><td>RE  WO 10101-1_BID3_Final_1 Brazoria Co.msg</td><td></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>10101-1_BID3</td><td></td><td></td><td>msg</td><td>RE  WO 10101-1_BID3 Brazoria Co Scope Variance.msg</td><td></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>10101-1_BID5</td><td></td><td></td><td>xlsx</td><td>10101-1_BID5_General_Review Checklist.xlsx</td><td></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>10101-1_BID5</td><td></td><td></td><td>xlsx</td><td>10101-1_BID5_Building (Structural)_Review Checklist.xlsx</td><td></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>10101-1_BID5</td><td></td><td></td><td>xlsx</td><td>10101-1_BID5_PC_Submittal_Review_Checklist.xlsx</td><td></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>10101-1_BID5</td><td></td><td></td><td>msg</td><td>WO 10101-1_BID5_30_1 Brazoria County.msg</td><td></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>10101-1_BID5</td><td></td><td>Brazoria County, Commodore Cove Elevated electrical and chlorine buildings at water plant and WWTP.</td><td>xlsx</td><td>10101-1_BID5 Checklist for Bid Docs.xlsx</td><td>Checklist for Bid Documents</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>10101-1_BID5</td><td></td><td></td><td>msg</td><td>WO 10101-1_BID5_Final_1 Brazoria County.msg</td><td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So for example, the code I have will write out the third row as:

```
10101-1_BID1***xlsx*10101-1_BID1_PC Submittal_Review Checklist.xlsx*
```

and I would like it to be:

```
10101-1*10101-1_BID1***xlsx*10101-1_BID1_PC Submittal_Review Checklist.xlsx*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have the woNumber for each file you are processing, you could change:

```
for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    rows.append([val.text.encode('utf-8') for val in row.find_all('td')])
```

To:

```
for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    rows.append([woNumber] + [val.text.encode('utf-8') for val in row.find_all('td')])
```

So that each row in `rows` contains the woNumber of the file you were processing at the time.

**Note:** This will change the logic in:

```
writer.writerows(row for row in rows if row)
```

Since now each row will contain it's woNumber even if there is no other information.  Therefore you can change it to:

```
writer.writerows(row for row in rows if len(row) != 1)
```

To only output rows with more information than just the woNumber.